# current selected item from a menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

adding the items to the menu selection making it to the group of items.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="user1">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Products</h3>                    
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
       <ul id="accordion" class="accordion" >
          <li ng-repeat="(key, categoryType) in categories">

            <div class="link" >{{categoryType.name}}
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </div>
            <ul ng-class="{submenu1: categoryType.name == 'Miscellaneous', submenu: categoryType.name != 'Miscellaneous'}">
              <li ng-repeat="item in categoryType[categoryType.name] track by $index"
                  ng-click="getProductDetails(item)">
                <a href="#">{{item.Name}}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>                      
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Rohan

Answer (score 0):

In Angular JS this is very easy:

First, create a CSS class to describe how the item will look once it is selected:

```
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Then, use `ng-class` to assign this class to an item whenever it is selected. You can place it on either the `li` or `a` tag. Your choice:

```
<li ng-class="{'selected': item.selected}"
    ng-repeat="item in categoryType[categoryType.name] track by $index"
    ng-click="getProductDetails(item)">
  <a href="#">{{item.Name}}</a>
</li>
```

Now you will need to modify the function that is called when you click the item, `getProductDetails` to mark the item as selected. You will also need to UNmark all the other items:

```
function getProductDetails(item) {
  var items = $scope.categoryType[categoryType.name];
  items.forEach(function(x) {
    x.selected = false;
  });
  item.selected = true;

  //... continue with the rest of your function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way than looping through all items in a list after every click would be to just create a scope variable to hold the selected item's index, and apply a class on the selected index only.

**CSS**

```
.selected {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list"
    ng-class="{'selected':selectedItem==$index}"
    ng-click="selectItem($index)">
  {{item.name}}
</li>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.selectItem = function(index) {
  $scope.selectedItem = index;
};
```